# iOS Swift 3: Setting UISearchBar ScopeButton text and Background color

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

I am working with a search bar that contains two scopes (Users and Groups) that i would like to make the button and text color the default blue and white depending on the selected state.

**Please see the screenshot below:**

[image]

I have set the background image for the searchbar/scopebars as seen below to produce a "clear" background:

```
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage()
```

As can be seen above, the background for the "Groups" scope button is clear rather than white and the same can be said for the "Users" text. Please note i am okay with the default iOS "Blue" color used for the border and the text of any unselected scopes. 
So my question is as follows:

**How do you set the color of the scope button background/text depending on the selected state?**

Comment: do you mean change the segment control's selected button's bacground color and text color?

Comment: Yes, the background/text color of the Users/Groups scope buttons seen above

Comment: including the border line?

Comment: I am okay with the default iOS blue for the background color of the selected scope and the text color of the unselected scope

Comment: just want to set the selected button's title color? or what?

Comment: See updated photo.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 method can help you:

```
    // this can set background image(image for background color)
    segment.setBackgroundImage(<#T##backgroundImage: UIImage?##UIImage?#>, for: <#T##UIControlState#>, barMetrics: <#T##UIBarMetrics#>)
    // this can set text color
    segment.setTitleTextAttributes(<#T##attributes: [AnyHashable : Any]?##[AnyHashable : Any]?#>, for: <#T##UIControlState#>)
```